# Updating a text box with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, textbox

I am having some trouble with some javascript and how it can control the html "text box".

First, here's what I have;
javascript:

```
function UpdateOrder()
{
    // enable/disable appropriate buttons
    document.getElementById("reset").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("add").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("edit").disabled=false;
    document.getElementById("update").disabled=true;

    // Show display box, 'DispCurOrder'
    document.getElementById('all_labels').disabled=true;
}

function EditOrder()
{
    // enable/disable appropriate buttons
    document.getElementById("reset").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("add").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("submit").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("edit").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("update").disabled=false;

    document.getElementById('all_labels').disabled=false;
}
```

The Idea is simple...  I have some buttons and inputs to generate a 'line' of text that get's dumped to the disabled text box.  If the operator notices that they made a type-o or want to change something, they click on 'edit order' and it disables all the regular buttons, and enables the text box and 'update' button.  The 'update order' button reverses this.

Now, when I just use the add lines to the text box, all works well.  You can see each line get appended to the text box (there's another java function that does a bunch of error checking and such, but the crux is that it takes the contents of the text box, parses it on the "\n" to an array, then appends the new line of text.  It then takes the array and puts it all together as a new string and puts it back into the text box.  Here is that portion without all the error checking stuff;

```
function AppendOrder()
{
    // let's set up an error flag.
    var AppendError="";
    var str1=document.forms["MyForm"].DataEntry1.value;
    var str2=document.forms["MyForm"].DataEntry2.value;

    if( /* checking variable str1 for errors */)
    {
        AppendError="Error in str 1 here";
    }

    if( /* checking variable str1 for errors */)
    {
        AppendError=AppendError+"Error in str 2 here";
    }

    // Display the error message, if there are no errors, it will clear what was there.
    $('#AppendStatus').html(AppendError);

    if(AppendError=="")
    {
        // it's all good, update the display
        // create line of text
        curEntry=str1 + " -- " + str2;

        // let's get the current order into a list
        str=document.getElementById('all_data').innerHTML;

        if(str1=="Empty")
        {
            // make curOrder = to 1 element array of curEntry
            var curOrder=[curEntry];
        }
        else
        {
            // parse str1 into an array and parse it to curOrder.
                    // Then push curEntry on the end.
            var curOrder=str1.split("\n");
            curOrder.push(curEntry);
        }

        // now we should have an array called 'curOrder[]'.  Let's show it 
            // on the web page.
        $('#all_labels').html(curOrder);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem that I'm having is that after I add a line or two (or more) to the display using the 'add' button and then go into the 'edit' mode (where the text box is enabled) and I make all my changes, the 'add' button doesn't work.

Oddly enough, when I press the 'reset' button (which is just a reset button) it then shows all the adds I did after the edit, and the edited stuff is gone.

Now... to the question...  is there something I'm not understanding about the text box?  Is there some trick I need to do to get it to work?  Am I going about this all wrong?  Should I be using a different tool for this other than the 'textbox'?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Greg

Comment: Is the textbox (all_labels?) element a textarea or an `<input type="text" etc >` or ?

Comment: Yes, the text box is a textarea...  I knew I was going to forget to put some bit of information here...

<textarea rows="4" cols="100" id="all_labels" name="all_labels" disabled>Empty</textarea>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the typo in [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8My4X/8/).

The first thing that I did was to add:

```
alert('hi there');
```

to the very top of the script, inside the `$(document).ready()` wrapper. Note that on jsFiddle you cannot see the document.ready wrapper, it is invisibly included, so just put the alert at top of javascript block as I did (link to my new jsFiddle is at bottom of answer)

Next, I noticed that you are enabling/disabling several controls by referencing them individually by ID. You can reference several controls at one time if they share the same class, so I invented the `class="orderentry"` and added that attribute to each of those controls. This removed 8 lines of code, which made troubleshooting easier.

Then, I began deleting/undeleting.  First, I deleted everything in the javascript panel except `alert('hi there');`, and ran the jsFiddle. The alert popped up.  Great. So I used Ctrl+z to undelete everything. Next, I selected everything EXCEPT the next block of code, and deleted the selection. I ran the jsFiddle, and again the alert popped up.

I continued deleting/undeleting until I found out where the alert no longer worked -- and that revealed the offending code block. Just had to carefully study the syntax in that specific area and found the error:

```
$('#txtOrder').attr({'disabled':'disabled')};  <== ERROR: note final parentheses
```

instead of

```
$('#txtOrder').attr({'disabled':'disabled'});  <== CORRECT: note final parentheses
```

Hope this helped, good luck on the rest of your project.

Here is [the corrected jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8My4X/9/)

Comment: This is perfect!!  Thanks very much!!!!  I figured the error was something silly like that -- good catch.  I'm going to use that 'alert' method of trouble shooting in the future.  I think I'll use the comments rather than deleting the code outright, though:)  Thank again!!

Comment: If you are using a modern browser (anything more modern than IE8) for development then I would strongly suggest using console.log rather than alert to log out as and when you reach code points - unlike alert it is non-interupting/non-modal so your code will continue rather than pause until you dismiss the dialogue. I'd also suggest you look into your browsers developer tools (Firefox and Chrome have a particularly good set) which will give you very good visibility into where errors are occurring in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't share your HTML, so I made assumptions about what your markup looks like.

[Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8My4X/)

The above jsFiddle is a much simplified version of what you are creating. Obviously, it is very different from what you have done so that I could create it quickly.

Observe how I made certain things happen with jQuery; take what is useful and ignore the rest.

Specifically, you can see how I initially disabled the textarea control:

```
$('#txtArea').attr({'disabled':'disabled'});
```

Re-enabled the textarea control for editing, while also hiding the Edit button and displaying the Save button:

```
$('#txtArea').removeAttr('disabled');
$('#btnSave').show();
$(this).hide();
```

Importantly, this is how I ensure each addition adds to (rather than overwriting) existing content:

```
var ord = 'Requested By: ' + $('#txtReq').val() + '\r\n';
```

Very likely you already know many (most?) of the things I am pointing out, but I have no idea what you know so, again, keep the one or two things you find useful and ignore the rest. *I only hope I've managed to hit on the bit that has you stumped at the moment.*

---

I very rarely recommend W3Schools for anything, but [look here for their excellent summary / reference of jQuery selectors, events, methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp). (Keep hitting `Next Chapter` to cycle through all pages of this reference).

Comment: thanks!!!  This is almost _exactly_ what I'm looking for!  As for what I know and don't know...  well, I know enough to know that I have only scratched the surface of what I want to know as far as Java scripting goes.  I know the basics of HTML and Java and I'm trying to teach myself to be a guru.  Been coding for a long time in various languages.

One question thought...  why do you not recommend W3Schools?  I've been reading alot of that stuff.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Greg. Please accept answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: I have been playing with that jsfiddle.  I can't get it to work right for me.  I think I must be doing something completely idiotic...  What I did was to combine all the inputs into one 'add' button, and then the edit and save buttons disable/enable the fields accordingly.  For some reason, when I did this, all the buttons stopped doing anything...<sigh>...  Here's the fiddle after I modified it.  Thanks again for you input!!!  http://jsfiddle.net/8My4X/8/

Comment: Found your typo -- I added my new comments [as a new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18623500/updating-a-text-box-with-javascript/18747603#18747603) so that I could properly format what I wished to say.